# unable to start workers in celery

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I am using Django rest framework to do prediction on two strings and using celery to run inference. But I was unable to make use of celery workers even though I have done everything perfectly. I am getting predictions from drf only

I am using redis as a broker.

My `tasks.py`

```py
@shared_task(bind=True)
def predictions(self,solute, solvent):

    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(solute)
    mol = Chem.AddHs(mol)
    solute = Chem.MolToSmiles(mol)
    solute_graph = get_graph_from_smile(solute)

    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(solvent)
    mol = Chem.AddHs(mol)
    solvent = Chem.MolToSmiles(mol)
    solvent_graph = get_graph_from_smile(solvent)
    delta_g, interaction_map = model([solute_graph.to(device), solvent_graph.to(device)])
    return delta_g, torch.trunc(interaction_map)
```

My `views.py`

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def result(request):
    response = {}
    solute = request.GET.get('solute')
    solvent = request.GET.get('solvent')
    results = predictions(solute,solvent)
    response["interaction_map"] = (results[1].detach().numpy()).tolist()

    response["predictions"] = results[0].item()

    return Response({'result': response}, status=200)
```

I guess the problem is not adding `.delay()` to `results = predictions(solute,solvent)` but if I add `results = predictions(solute,solvent).delay()` I am getting error.

My `flower` panel
[image]

Even though I am getting my prediction perfectly without any error their is no celery task is running please help me where I am doing wrong

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: while using `results = predictions(solute,solvent).delay()` i am getting error `predictions() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'solute' and 'solvent'` but i am passing solute and solvent @BrianDestura

Comment: By using `delay`, it should be: `predictions.delay(solute,solvent)`

Comment: @BrianDestura then I am getting `'AsyncResult' object is not subscriptable
` error

Comment: You might want to revisit the [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html) for this. At least in this case, you will have to do `results.get()` to get the result

Comment: If i am using `.get()` as then i am getting `NotImplementedError at /predict/
No result backend is configured.
Please see the documentation for more information.` Error @BrianDestura